# is there a way to place the last divs ontop of first without overlapping the divs

Tags: html, css

i have an upload script that shows all already uploaded pictures in divs with class="download"

when i add more pictures with a jquery script it adds those images in divs with class="upload"

these uploads i want to show above the divs with class="download"

but the code automaticly puts it below

i know there must be a way with css but i cant seem to get it working

```
<div id="files" class="files">
<div id="download" class="download"></div>
<div id="download" class="download"></div>
<div id="download" class="download"></div>
<div id="download" class="download"></div>
<div id="download" class="download"></div>
<div id="upload" class="upload"></div>
<div id="upload" class="upload"></div>
<div id="upload" class="upload"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox with [`order`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) to solve this. This solution also works in case the uploads and downloads are mixed and the original order of elements is retained (first upload remains first upload).

```css
.files {
  display:flex;
}
.files .download {
  order:2;
}
.files .upload {
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="files" class="files">
  <div id="download" class="download">1.1</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.2</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.3</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.4</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.5</div>
  <div id="upload" class="upload">2.1</div>
  <div id="upload" class="upload">2.2</div>
  <div id="upload" class="upload">2.3</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.6</div>
  <div id="download" class="download">1.7</div>
  <div id="upload" class="upload">2.4</div>
  <div id="upload" class="upload">2.5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: jup this works however it also destroys the whole responsive design
the divs are not responsive anymore

Comment: correction it works. i looked that flex thing up on google and all i needed to add was flex-wrap: wrap;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css applying this to the parent:

```css
    .files {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
```

This will apply the flex layout rules and display them in a reversed column.

A more robust solution might be to have the script `prepend` the images instead of `append`ing them. If you have access to the script, and since you already mentioned jQuery, you can take a look at the methods:

- https://api.jquery.com/prepend/
- https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

They work in different ways, but both allow you to prepend elements to other elements. Depending on how the script works, you can try either of them.